# Apropriate rights to access "manage site features"

Tags: 2010, permissions, administration

I am fairly new to sharepoint, and I am currently trying to add features to an existing wiki.
I would like enable metadata navigation, and thus need to enable this feature, as it is curently turned off. However, on the "Site Action">"Site Settings" tab, I can't see any mention of the "Manage site features" option.

I therefore suspect I don't have the necessary rights to access those settings, despite having "Full control" rights on the sub-site I work on. 
What level of rights do I need to enable/disable site features ? Are they accessible through the online interface or do they need to be configured on the server side ?

Comment: Are you the site collection administrator of that site?

Comment: Manage site data in the 1st option under Site Actions, can you see site actions on the page that appears when you click on site settings, if not then you donot have the priviledges.

Comment: Would you please try entering the Site collection features or Manage site features page directly via the URL to see if it works?
For Site collection features page, it is https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx.
For Manage site features page, the address is https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site.

Comment: Thanks luckydeveloper, this worked (without the 15 in the url)

Comment: Sorry /15 is for SharePoint 2013

Comment: Please go to Site Settings-->Site Permissions -- > check permissions(on ribbon). Type in the user name and verify whether you are having "Full control".It will display the current permission applied to that user.